# Ajax loader handling problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, jquery

I have a number of edit links which remotely pull on an edit form, which is brought up in an overlay. In order to give feedback to users I have a span which replaces the original *edit-tester* link while the call is being made. Upon completion the span is removed correctly. The problem is, when clicking on the same link again 2 *'thinking'* spans appear. When clicked again 3 appear and so on.

Could anyone advise on why this is and how to fix it based on the sample code below?

I obviously want only 1 'thinking' span to appear whenever the link is pressed, not multiplicities dependent on the number of clicks.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
$('a.edit-tester').click(function() {
  $(this).bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    $(this).after('<span class="thinking">Thinking</span>');
  }).bind('ajax:success', function() {
   $('span.thinking').remove();
    $(this).toggle(); 
}).bind('ajax:error', function(){
     $('span.thinking').remove();
     $(this).toggle();  
   });
});
```

My only guess is that the actual *'thinking'* span is not being removed from the DOM. Other than that it's anybody's guess...

EDIT: Edited the first line of the code above... I forgot to change it back after messing around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding additional copies of the send event to the link with each click.  See how

```
 $(this).bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {...}
```

is actually done each time the link is clicked?  You could probably move that block to before or after the parent function and it'd work fine.

Edit: To clarify, it appears that you're chaining all your events into a single expression.  Chaining in jQuery is powerful, but this isn't what it's for.  Without seeing more of your source I can't suggest a specific implementation, but for just adding the "thinking" DIV this will do the job:

```
$('a.edit-tester').live('click', function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    $(this).after('<span class="thinking">Thinking</span>');
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, there was no reason to bind the function after a click was performed. I removed the .click call and it all works gravy now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem.  I made the same mistake when I started with jQuery - it's especially easy considering how strongly the use of chaining is pushed in the jQuery docs, they're very proud of it.  ;) Coincidentally, if I've helped you it's polite to vote up the post in addition to accepting it, although this isn't required.  In any case, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would've voted your reply up, but it says I have to have at least 15 rep to do it... I'm currently on 5. I'll vote this answer up when I get the rep. :) Thx for the welcome! :)

Comment: Oh, don't worry about it.  Doesn't make much difference.  Good luck with your application.